# Create a numpy array with zeros and ones at random positions

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using Python 3.7.7.

I want to create a Numpy array with random values between 1 and 0. I have found that I can create an array with all of its elements equal to zero:

```
zeros = np.zeros((960, 200, 200, 1))
```

Or equal to one:

```
ones = np.ones((960, 200, 200, 1))
```

Those functions return an array with all of its elements equals.

I want to create an array with its elements are zero or one at random positions.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you trying to create an array with zeros and ones at random positions?

Comment: Randon values between 0 and 1: maybe you want this? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random.html

Comment: @FBruzzesi Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved in many ways using numpy, the most straightforward being:

```
size = (960, 200, 200, 1)
np.random.randint(0, 2, size=size)
```

If you don't want uniform distribution of zeros and ones, this can be controlled directly using [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
size = (960, 200, 200, 1)
proba_0 = 0.8                 # resulting array will have 80% of zeros
np.random.choice([0, 1], size=size, p=[proba_0, 1-proba_0])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can draw numbers from [0,1] and ask if they are larger than a threhold value:

```
threshold = 0.5
a = 1*(np.random.rand(960, 200, 200, 1)> threshold)
```