# create a numpy array with zeros and ones at random positions BUT at least one or more '1's on a given sub axis

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am looking to make a numpy array randomly initialized with zeros and ones, I found the following question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451108/create-a-numpy-array-with-zeros-and-ones-at-random-positions) that descripbes the basic random array and how to control the dimensions. However, I need my array to have at least a single '1' on each sub array of the nested axis. See example:

```
import numpy as np    
size = (3, 5, 5)
proba_0 = 0.7
n_positions = np.random.choice([0,1], size=size, p=[proba_0, 1-proba_0])
print(n_positions)

[[[0 1 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 1 1]
  [1 0 0 0 0]
  [0 1 0 0 0]]

 [[0 1 1 1 1]
  [0 0 1 1 0]
  [1 0 0 1 1]
  [0 0 1 0 0]
  [0 1 0 1 1]]

 [[0 0 0 0 1]
  [0 0 1 0 1]
  [0 0 0 0 1]
  [0 0 0 1 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]]]
```

This issue here is that at the following position in this array `n_positions[0][1]` the data is populted ONLY with zeros. I need there to be at least one '1' in each row on axis 2. I can increase the probability of 1s occuring but this doesn't eliminate the risk.

I could make this with a loop or a comprehension using a method getting numpy to generate a random numer of ones between 1-5 and then filling out with zeros but its very slow. I am hoping there is a more numpy friendly method built in to achieve this?

Comment: You need a 1 for every axis 2? Or every axis. For example, I see also that `[:,0,0]` is also all 0 (so along axis 0, at pos `*,0,0`. Or `[2,:,1]` (column 1 of plane 2) is also all 0. Are these other examples of all-0 axis that must but filled with at least one 1? Or do you mean that along last axis only, there must be a 1?

Comment: In other words, is the condition for array to be ok `arr.any(axis=2).all()`? Or is it `arr.any(axis=0).all() and arr.any(axis=1).all() and arr.any(axis=2).all()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution (in case you only want to fill last axis. If you want to do this for all axes, then you need to repeat it for all axes, I guess)

```py
def fillLastAxis(arr):
    # Position in all but last axes of rows that need a 1
    pos=~arr.any(axis=-1) # True on rows coords that miss a 1
    # Number of 1 to generate
    num=pos.sum()
    # Index (along the last axis, of the missing 1)
    idx=np.random.randint(0, arr.shape[-1], num)
    # Just add a one at this pos
    arr[pos, idx]=1
```

Testing:

```py
size = (3, 5, 5)
proba_0 = 0.7
n_positions = np.random.choice([0,1], size=size, p=[proba_0, 1-proba_0])
print("==== Before ====")
print(n_positions)
fillLastAxis(n_positions)
print("==== After ====")
print(n_positions)
```

Shows

```
==== Before ====
[[[1 0 1 1 1]
  [1 0 0 0 1]
  [0 1 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [1 0 1 0 1]]

 [[0 0 1 0 1]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 1]
  [0 1 1 0 1]
  [0 0 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 1]
  [0 0 0 1 1]
  [1 1 1 0 1]
  [0 1 0 0 0]
  [0 1 0 0 1]]]
==== After ====
[[[1 0 1 1 1]
  [1 0 0 0 1]
  [0 1 0 0 0]
  [0 1 0 0 0]
  [1 0 1 0 1]]

 [[0 0 1 0 1]
  [0 0 1 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 1]
  [0 1 1 0 1]
  [0 0 0 1 0]]

 [[0 0 0 0 1]
  [0 0 0 1 1]
  [1 1 1 0 1]
  [0 1 0 0 0]
  [0 1 0 0 1]]]
```

You can see that row 3 of plane 0, and row 1 of plane 1 are missing a 1 before. And have one (at position 1 and 2) after.

With higher dimension (to test with more axes, and reduce the probability that this was just luck). This times I force the seed, so that you can test at home, and check the result, without the need for me to print the whole array, since you have the same.

```py
size = (3, 6, 4, 5)
proba_0 = 0.5
np.random.seed(12)
n_positions = np.random.choice([0,1], size=size, p=[proba_0, 1-proba_0])
print("==== Before ====")
print(n_positions)
fillLastAxis(n_positions)
print("==== After ====")
print(n_positions)
```

If I am correct, there are 3 all-0 lines in the result (`[0,2,1,:]`, `[2,0,3,:]` and `[2,4,3,:]`). And they are all filled with one random 1 after.

Comment: This is great, thanks for that! I have a slightly different solution but I think yours is faster, will do some more testing and then post.